# Insert data into Microsoft SQL Server 2012 from Oracle using DB lInk

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle

Here is the Scenario :

I want to insert data from oracle database to SQL Server database  using db link by running a procedure which involves a loop where one row of data have to be inserted in sql server database .every time the loop executes. while executing insert statement in oracle ,  following error is shown .

> *****ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message: [Generic Connectivity Using ODBC][Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot insert the value NULL into column
>   'item_description', table 'STS.dbo.item'; column does not allow nulls.
>   INSERT fails.[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The
>   statement has been terminated. (SQL State: 23000; SQL Code: 515)
>   ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from RMS2STS*****

Data type of the column "item_description " is long and the data i am trying to insert is Varchar2(4000) which should not be a problem because i can insert a row in sql server using single oracle insert statement.

for eg : single insert statement works :

```
insert into "item"@rms2sts("item_code","item_description","item_type")
values (100,'test',1);
```

following insert statement in the loop of oracle procedure is throwing the error

```
insert into "item"@rms2sts("item_code","item_description","item_type")
values(item_id,item_desc,type_id)
```

these variable have the value to be inserted.

I have made sure there are no null values getting generated in loop for the specified column.

Can you please tell me why this error is generated ?

Comment: You say item_description is a long. From the sample insert data you give it is not, but item_type could be. ('long' isn't a SQLServer data type but I guess I know what you mean.) Make the item_description column nullable, then re-run your conversion. When finished select where item_description is null, and that'll identify the problem rows which you can then address.

Comment: Yeah the datatype is not long , it is varchar(max) which is considered long in oracle .

As you suggested ,i made a copy of the sql server  table with the same column nullable. Then i executed the insert procedure , one row got inserted. when i checked the sql server table after that ,item_description value for that row is null . But the value inserted from oracle procedure was not null. this is not issue with the data,

Comment: Can you identify the Oracle row that got the null in SQLServer? If so, what's different about it to other rows?

Comment: row from oracle database which  is inserted : 
(100001203,'BELT~BGFA087BT-1 / M/L',1)

when you check the sql server database  it  shows
(1000001203 null 1 )

If you insert the same values in a single insert statement other than an oracle procedure , proper values are inserted.

any ideas why ?